# dataGridView image column link to file

Tags: c#, image, file, user-interface, datagridview

I am working with an image column on dataGridView:

As shown in the attached picture, when I click on 'browse' I can choose a file from the dialog window.

**What I want...**

is to make the image on the 'Files' image-column to link to the chosen file (to get the file open when the user clicks on the image).

I have no idea how to make that happen. Could anyone give me a direction?
[image]

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

First You can create your own Class and put in this class Property for File Path 
I've created example :

```
public class MyClass
    {
       public string Name{get;set;}
       public string FilePath{ get; set; }// Here i put The path and it will not appear in the Grid will just show the first item
    }
```

in DataGrid there is an event called *SelectionChanged* you can add this code there

```
if (DG.CurrentColumn.Header.ToString() == "Name")
                Process.Start((DG.SelectedItem as MyClass).FilePath);
```

when i select the item it will open the folder you can put instead of ("Name") your column name ("Brows")