# C# dataGridView image column link to file

Tags: c#, user-interface, file, image

I am working with an image column on dataGridView:

As shown in the attached picture, when I click on 'browse' I can choose a file from the dialog window.

### What I want...

is to make the image on the 'Files' image-column to link to the chosen file (to get the file open when the user clicks on the image).

I have no idea how to make that happen. Could anyone give me a direction?[image: the 'Files' column is an image-column]

Comment: This question might be a better fit for StackOverflow as it is a very specific question relating to C#, Programmers.SE is more about software development in general.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dataGridView image column link to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186792/datagridview-image-column-link-to-file)